# Working with array and Dictionaries after loading them from Disk using np.load and np.save

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, save, load

I have several huge arrays, and I am using np.save and np.load to save each array or dictionary in a single file and then I reload them, in order not to compute them another time as follows.

```
save(join(dir, "ListTitles.npy"), self.ListTitles)
self.ListTitles = load(join(dir,"ListTitles.npy"))
```

The problem is that when I try to use them afterwards, I have errors like (field name not found) or (len() of unsized object).
For example:

```
 len(self.ListTitles) or when accessing a field of a dictionary return an error.
```

I don't know how to resolve this. Because when I simply use this code, it works perfectly:

```
M = array([[1,2,0], [3,4,0], [3,0,1]])
vector = zeros(3529)
save("M.npy", M)
save("vector.npy", vector)
vector = load("vector.npy")
B = load("M.npy")
print len(B)
print len(vector)
```

Comment: What is `self.ListTitles`?  An array, list, dictionary,...?

Comment: is a dictionnary like {'repondr': 0, 'cytometr': 2, 'dynamic': 3}, I also have some non-numpy lists and some numpy arrays as well. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy`'s `save` and `load` functions are **for `numpy` arrays**, not for general Python data like `dict`s.  Use the `pickle` module to save to file, and reload from file, most kinds of Python data structures (there are alternatives like `dill` which are however not in the standard library -- I'd recommend sticking with standard `pickle` unless it gives you specific problems).

Comment: I think the `scipy.io.savemat` (matlab format) can also handle other objects.